# How to get the FileList from a file input in a Blazor method

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor

I know how to get this working when using the Blazor <InputFile...> component.

```
<InputFile accept="image" OnChange="HandleImagePickerResult"></InputFile>
...
private async void HandleImagePickerResult(InputFileChangeEventArgs eventArgs) { ... }
```

and from this I can get the file or files selected from eventArgs.

But what if I want to get these files without using <InputFile...> ? I just want to use a standard html input type=file?

When my onchange fires I always end up with an element called "files" in the eventArgs that is null.

What type should I make the parameter in the HandleImagePicker result or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I still recommend using `<InputFile>` because we are now writing blazor app but not basic html app, so using the built-in module would help us reduce much trouble. And if we have to use standard html + js, let's see my test result.

First of all, if we want to do the file input onchange event, we can have codes like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>home page here</p>
        <div>
            <label>upload file</label>
            <input type="file" id="img1" multiple="multiple" onchange="myFunction(this.files)" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>upload file2</label>
            <input type="file" id="img2" multiple="multiple" />
        </div>
        
        <script>
            function myFunction(files){
                for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    let file = files[i];
                    console.info(file);
                    alert(file.name)
                }
            }
            
            document.getElementById('img2').addEventListener('change',function(e){
                    for(let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
                        let file = this.files[i];
                        alert(file.name);
                    }
                },false)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But if we added the scripts into razor component directly, we will face issue

```
@page "/counter"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<div>
    <label>upload file</label>
    <input type="file" id="img1" multiple="multiple" onchange="myFunction(this.files)" />
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction(files) {
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            let file = files[i];
            console.info(file);
            alert(file.name)
        }
    }
</script>

<InputFile OnChange="@LoadFiles" multiple />

@code {

    private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = e.GetMultipleFiles();
    }
    
}
```

like this, can't load scripts after rendering, still need a refresh in browser.

[image]

So I followed [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#load-a-script-from-an-external-javascript-file-js-collocated-with-a-component) to inject js, so I created a js collocated with a component named `Counter.razor.js`

```
export function myFunction(files) {
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let file = files[i];
        console.info(file);
        alert(file.name)
    }
}
export function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById('img2').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
            let file = this.files[i];
            alert(file.name);
        }
    }, false)
}
```

and inject it in `OnAfterRenderAsync` method. And my code looks like this finally, the second input could work as expected.

```
@page "/counter"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<div>
    <label>upload file</label>
    <input type="file" id="img1" multiple="multiple" onchange="myFunction(this.files)" />
</div>

<div>
    <label>upload file</label>
    <input type="file" id="img2" multiple="multiple" />
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction(files) {
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            let file = files[i];
            console.info(file);
            alert(file.name)
        }
    }
</script>

<InputFile OnChange="@LoadFiles" multiple />

@code {
    private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = e.GetMultipleFiles();
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Pages/Counter.razor.js");
            await module.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("myFunction2");
        }
    }
}
```